# Single word verb for "to stay up late"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am making a decorative chalkboard for my daughter's birthday.

I plan to list the things she can do:

- **Swim** like a fish
- **Jump** like a frog
- **Climb** like a monkey
- **Stay up late** like an owl.

I want a single word verb to replace "stay up late" so I can maintain the pattern.

Comment: It's archaic, but *wake like an owl* is probably the closest you're going to get. The verb *to wake* used to describe the state of being awake, not the action of coming awake as we use it now (you still see vestiges of this in the adjectives *awake* and *wakeful*, which again both describe the state, not the action).

Comment: Another suitable archaism might be the (only ever rare) verb usage for ***vigil***. For which OED has a 1915 citation *Two days and two nights has he vigiled — the doctor dozes and blinks.*

Comment: You could try the word *nocturnalise* - but don't tell anyone I suggested it.

Comment: Watch, monitor, observe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a verb word that means what you want, but the idiom ***night owl*** is used to denote the inclination to stay up late. So,

> ***Night*** like an owl.

Comment: Or perhaps shorter: ***prowl like an owl***.